# Http 304 recieved for application heartbeat

Tags: jquery, http, session

I am trying to implement an application heartbeat using jquery.

The idea of my change is that I am going to reduce my application session-timeout from 30 minutes to 10 minutes but also implement a jquery application heartbeat every 2 minutes (120 seconds). The heartbeat will avoid the user receiving an application timeout when the browser is open but if the browser is closed then the session should timeout in 10 minutes.

I've implemented my heartbeat using jquery as follows...

```
var heartbeatInterval = 120000; // Send heartbeat every 2 mins
var heartBeatTimer = null;
var retryCount = 0;
var maxRetries = 10;

$().ready(function() {     

    // register heart beat to the server to keep the session alive.
    heartBeatTimer = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: heartBeatAjaxServletUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(data) {
                // The server may be down for the night or there may be a 
                // network blip. As such try to send the heart beat 10 times
                // then if still failing kill the heartbeat.
                retryCount = retryCount + 1;
                if (heartBeatTimer != null && retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                    clearInterval(heartBeatTimer);
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // Once we have a successful heartbeat reset the retry count.
                retryCount = 0;
            }
        });
        // When communication with the server is lost stop the heartbeat.
        }, heartbeatInterval);  
});
```

When I open up the Network tab in the Internet Explorer developer tools I can see the heart beat is working but the responses I am getting are 304's instead of 200's. When I did some research on 304 the explanation for this response code has something to do with http caching. I am a bit unsure of the the explanation to be honest.

[image]

But the crux of the problem is that the my user's session is timing out when the browser is open regardless of the heartbeat. I'm guessing that this means that the heartbeat I'm sending every two minites is returning not actually hitting the server?

Can someone help me with an explanation of what might be happening here and whey my session is timing out?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cache:false` option which will append a timestamp to url thereby making it unique

Reference [$.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks for that. So then it is the browser that is caching the request?

Comment: would appear to be yes